# Deleting all items in struct array C

Tags: c

I have an struct like this:

```
struct DEPT {
    char dept_name[20];
    int time;
    int num;
    int check;
    struct CAR car;
    struct CAR arr[10];
    struct DEPT *next_dept;
    struct DEPT *prev_dept;
    struct DEPT *next_sibling;
};
```

there are something in arr[10]. I have a function and i want to when the function begin, arr[10] should be empty.How can i do that?

---

Actually, i have a linked list. I didn't have something like struct DEPT dept. I tried that but it fails

```
  while (temp != NULL) {
    temp=(struct DEPT*){ .arr={(struct CAR){0}} };
    sibling = temp->next_sibling;
    while (sibling != NULL) {
        sibling=(struct DEPT*){ .arr={(struct CAR){0}} };
        sibling = sibling->next_sibling;
    }
    temp = temp->next_dept;  
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that the `arr` member should be *initialized*? Because arrays in C are never "*empty*".

Comment: Yes, it should be initialized

Comment: Just reassign them right away

Comment: `sibling=(struct DEPT*){ .arr={(struct CAR){0}} };` ----> `memset(sibling->arr, 0, sizeof(struct CAR) };`

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
struct DEPT dept = {0};
```

Or:

```
struct DEPT dept;
memset(&dept, 0, sizeof(dept));
```

**UPDATE: only dept_name of struct is set to 0:**

```
memset(&dept.dept_name, 0, sizeof(dept.dept_name));
```

Comment: But if i use first one i would initalize all dept struct i want to only initalize dept.arr[10] array.

Comment: Ok, so you only want to initialize part of struct to 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this example helps you.

```
struct xyz
{

        int data;
};

struct
{
        struct xyz str[3];
        struct xyz arr[10];
}abc={.arr[0 ... 2].data = 5 };




int main()
{
        printf("....%d\n",abc.arr[0].data);
        printf("....%d\n",abc.arr[1].data);
        printf("....%d\n",abc.arr[2].data);
        printf("....%d\n",abc.str[0].data);
        printf("....%d\n",abc.str[1].data);
        printf("....%d\n",abc.str[2].data);
}
```

Answer:-

```
....5
....5
....5
....0
....0
....0
```

This is non-standard C. And you can initialize it "partially" without mixing in non-standard things, for example

```
.arr = { [0].data=5, [1].data=5, [2].data=5 }.
```

Comment: This is non-standard GNU code and not standard C. The OP never mentioned using the gcc compiler.

Comment: @Lundin i wanna show him, he can initialize structure partially.

Comment: You should still clarify that this is non-standard C. And you can initialize it "partially" without mixing in non-standard things, for example `.arr = { [0].data=5, [1].data=5, [2].data=5 }`.